# Sortable select2 swap value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-select2, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to change the value inside my select2 using sortable but in no vain .. I've tried swapping looping through the values inside the stop function but I can't seem to get it right.

Here is my simplified code :

```js
$(".select2").select2();

$("ul.select2-selection__rendered").sortable({
  containment: 'parent',
  stop: function(event, ui) {
  console.log($("#form").serializeArray())
  }
});

console.log($("#form").serializeArray())
```

```css
.select2 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
        <select class="select2" name="test1" multiple>
          <option value="1" selected>test1</option>
          <option value="2" selected>test2</option>
          <option value="3" selected>test3</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The drag and drop works, but I want to be able to change value with them so the `console.log` prints out the re-ordered values.

Any hints would be much appreciated as to how one can use sortable with select2 to swap options in select.

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/763opz0c/4/

Comment: why are you not updating a value before rendering it

Comment: @NegiRox what do you mean? how so?

Comment: please take a look hope you are looking same solution. if no then i will make a new one with your requirement. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52927099/assign-a-index-value-to-the-list-element-value-dynamically-in-sortable-jquery/52927560#52927560

Comment: @NegiRox I wasn't able to reproduce it for my code (sorry, I'm new to JS...), could you kindly show me how ? I upvoted your answer there tho, thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184510/discussion-between-negi-rox-and-gumakettell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach to do that:

`select2` stores the data within the list items which we can use/map as per the requirements. Here's a console log of how the data is stored by **select2**

```js
$(".select2").select2({width: '300px'});

console.log($("ul.select2-selection__rendered").find('li.select2-selection__choice').data());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.css" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="row_0">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
        <select class="select2" name="test1" id="test1_0" multiple>
          <option value="1" selected>test1</option>
          <option value="2" selected>test2</option>
          <option value="3" selected>test3</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using the above data, we can map the list items' data within the `stop` callback:

```js
$(".select2").select2({width: '400px'});

$("ul.select2-selection__rendered").sortable({
  containment: 'parent',
  stop: function(event, ui) {
  // event target would be the <ul> which also contains a list item for searching (which has to be excluded)
    var arr = Array.from($(event.target).find('li:not(.select2-search)').map(function () { 
       return {name: $(this).data('data').text, value: $(this).data('data').id }; 
      }))
    console.log(arr);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.css" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="row_0">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
        <select class="select2" name="test1" id="test1_0" multiple>
          <option value="1" selected>test1</option>
          <option value="2" selected>test2</option>
          <option value="3" selected>test3</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT: To make form's serializearray to work as mentioned**

Using the `arr` above, we can just sort the options based on the values within `arr` and the `#form.serializearray()` will have no issues at all. Here's how:

```js
$(".select2").select2({width: '400px'});

$("ul.select2-selection__rendered").sortable({
  containment: 'parent',
  stop: function(event, ui) {
  // event target would be the <ul> which also contains a list item for searching (which has to be excluded)
    var arr = Array.from($(event.target).find('li:not(.select2-search)').map(function () { 
       return {name: $(this).data('data').text, value: $(this).data('data').id }; 
      }))
    //console.log(arr);
  
    var select = $(event.target).parents('span.select2-container').prev('select');
  // sort the options based on arr
    select.find('option').each(function (i, option) {
     option.value = arr[i].value;
      $(option).text(arr[i].name);
    });
    
    console.log($("#form").serializeArray());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.css" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="row_0">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
        <select class="select2" name="test1" id="test1_0" multiple>
          <option value="1" selected>test1</option>
          <option value="2" selected>test2</option>
          <option value="3" selected>test3</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I explicitly said that I wanted `console.log($("#form").serializeArray())` to work as I'm using it outside the `stop` in several places with several other forms depending on the changed values of each `select2`. So I can't only have your `arr` variable work that way; it's not dynamic enough.

Comment: Okay. We can always make the `.serializeArray` to work but I feel if you're using `select2` already in your app, it's better to take advantages of it's APIs. I hope you're aware of how `select2` works, right? `form.serializeArray` looks for it's child options/inputs which are no longer used by `select2` (after initialization I mean) and so it always gives out the initial value. If you still want it to work, you have to reorder the options based on the `sortable` order.

Comment: I know and I understand, but considering my code and how I can't change it as much as I want to I'm afraid I have to work my way around the `serializeArray()` function... Could you help me do that please? :)

Comment: Sure. You think based on what I have as of now- the `arr`, we can switch/reorder the values of select2 so that whenever you use this "outside" the `stop`, it'll still have the swapped order. Would that be okay? Anyway, I'll post an edit to this post related to swapping of actual options so that `.serializeArray` gives out the swapped order. I'll do that in a while.

Comment: Yes! That's what I want, to reorder the values in the dom kinda so the `serializeArray()` would work! :D

Comment: Lol I mentioned two separate options there. Anyway our main goal is the same. :) I'll edit the post in a while.

Comment: Oops sorry didn't notice, but I suppose you got the idea of what I'm trying to do :P Thanks a lot!

Comment: So, any idea? :D

Comment: So sorry about it as I got too busy with work (had a release). I'll get it done this weekend for sure (if you can wait), alright? Until then, I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561999/how-to-make-a-select2-4-0-sortable) if it helps.

Comment: No need for that. I just wrote a solution quickly. Editing the post right away :)

Comment: I'll need to adapt it to my code as I got errors but holy mother forking shirt balls (The good place reference) this is perfect, thank you!

Comment: Haha. Glad I could help. Let me know if you face any issues with that. Tag me. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

hi you can update your  sortable function something like this.

```
$(".select2").select2();
var formData=[];
$("ul.select2-selection__rendered").sortable({
  containment: 'parent',
  stop: function(event, ui) {
      formData=[];
      var _li= $('li.select2-selection__choice');
        _li.each(function(idx) {
          var currentObj=$(this);
          var data=currentObj.text();
          data=data.substr(1,data.length);
          formData.push({name:data,value:currentObj.val()})
     })
        console.log(formData)
  },
   update: function() {
        var _li= $('li');
       // _li.removeAttr("value");
        _li.each(function(idx) {
          var currentObj=$(this);
          console.log(currentObj.text());
          $(this).attr("value", idx + 1);
        })
   }
});
```

Please take a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/763opz0c/18/)

Comment: updated fiddle and code so you can use formData anywhere

Comment: It still doesn't do what I'm asking, the question is clear that I want `console.log($("#form").serializeArray())` to work, I'm not looking for a workaround .. Thanks for the help anyway :)